# SQL Server 2005 features in comparing DB schema /tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql

Is it possible to create or do it from SSMS to compare two different schema ?

I need to compare database table in my current production DB to see which one is different in order to generate delta (upgrade script)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but then I found this

select TABLE_SCHEMA,COUNT(*) TableCount from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES group by TABLE_SCHEMA
-- followed by
select * from sys.tables order by modify_date desc

but that's just a simple script to list all tables between my prod and dev environment.

Answer (score 4):

No, SSMS doesn't have a feature to do this.  Look at RedGate or Quest for a tool to do this.

Comment: SQLCompare by RedGate is the way to go (IMO)

Comment: Yes, I'll second the SQL Compare mention.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) - ApexSQL Diff is a SQL Server database comparison and synchronization tool which detects differences between database objects. It compares and synchronizes live databases, native or natively compressed database backups, database snapshots, scripts in source control and script folders

Video - [Introduction to ApexSQL Diff](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2brXfcSFAA)

Hope this helps

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*